# Смена title при помощи history.pushState

Tags: ajax, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Есть рабочий скрипт, url меняется, а вот как динамически менять title никак не могу понять.

```
<script> 
 $(function($){
 $('#menu a').attr('onclick','return false;').click(function(){ 
 var href = $(this).attr('href'); 
 $('.conteiner').fadeOut(90);
 $('.conteiner').load(href+' .conteiner', function(){ 
 history.pushState(null, null, href);$('.conteiner').fadeIn(600);return false;
 }); 
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Соответственно есть div с пунктами меню и div с классом conteiner подгружаемой части контента. Пробовал и pushState и replaceState но что-то ничего не работает. :(

Comment: thunder, огромное спасибо, всё работает! :))

Comment: ну и отлично)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.title="my new kewl title?";` не?

Comment: Неа, title должен подгружаться...получается, его нужно заключить в отдельный класс, который будет использоваться скриптом и подставляться после выполнения основного скрипта, при этом он должен быть связан с url адресом.

Comment: дык а что мещает это вызвать внутри вашего скрипта? это обычное свойство документа.... к history оно не имеет отношения.   
зыж ессно его вызов будет завязан на чтото) иначе откуда вы тайтл будете брать ;)

причем тут url адрес не очень понял.

Comment: На счёт url я и сам не понял :D
В принципе, title можно брать непосредственно из самой ссылки (пункта меню), т.е. a title и бла бла бла, и уже его подставлять вместо основного титла страницы.
http://kb-iskra.ucoz.ru/
Я вообще с js не знаком, всё делаю методом тыка.

Comment: да как хочется так и берется :) я ж не знаю как оно у вас работает.
если контент мвозвращается, к примеру, json, то можно в json запихнуть тайтл... ну вообщем это уже вопросы реализации. можно в возвразщаемой странице сделать какойто скрытое поле и оттуда читать title...

Comment: А ну вот, таперь меняется, не туда воткнул :) Теперь осталось только подгрузить этот title и вставить вместо my new kewl title?

Comment: ну да :) все просто поидее, если не начинать себя путать классами, обертками и урлами :)

Comment: В таком случае, как можно создать переменную со значениями из титлов ссылок (пунктов меню)?!

Comment: ну так читайте отттуда) в чем вопрос-то?   
вы же href читатете оттуда, так же и title читается и любой другой аттрибут, можетте свой собственный сделать аттрибут.  
эт уже на вашей совести откуда вы будете читать данные. :)